# Can I export an ECDSA xpub from my Ledger?

Tags: ledger, public-key

I just installed Tezos Wallet `v.2.2.9` on my Ledger Nano S and I would like to export an extended public key (xpub) from this wallet through Ledger Live. But I would like this xpub to generate addresses for the ECDSA curve, so addresses that start with `tz2`. How do I achieve that?

Currently I am only able to export compressed, single-use public keys, the ones that start with `02` or `03`. And the Tezos addresses that it generates all start with `tz1`, meaning that they are derived through ed25519 and not ECDSA secp256k1, as I would like.

Comment: There is something about the CLI in the comments linked below. Can I export an xpub for the Ledger through a tezos-CLI? https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/1078/tezos-cli-ledger-nano-tezbox-and-hd-wallet-problem-accessing-my-xtz?rq=1#comment1404_1107

Comment: Issue made on the Tezos Ledger repo
https://github.com/obsidiansystems/ledger-app-tezos/issues/159